# Union LARGE_INTEGER

Tags: c

This code is from MSDN. So, we have an union, which contains the struct and the variable. In my code I declared the prototype of union and then initialized the "QuadPart" of union. But printing the Quad Part doesn't give the full number but the LowPart of it. Is it a way it should be?

```
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER
{
        struct {
                unsigned LowPart;
                unsigned HighPart;
        } u;
        unsigned long long QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;


int main(int argc, char** argv){
        LARGE_INTEGER num1;
        num1.QuadPart = 0x1020304050607080;
        printf("Low: %x, high: %x, quad: %x\n", num1.u.LowPart, num1.u.HighPart, num1.QuadPart);


        return 0;
}
```

I expected the full number displayed by num1.QuadPart

Comment: Typo `quad: %x` should be `quad: %llx`, as the compiler should have said.

Comment: Uh, really, thanks. This is strange because compiler didn't say anything.

Comment: Actually, yes, but I forgot about this printing format and thought the problem is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `llx` for printing long long type printing in hex format

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER
{
        struct {
                unsigned LowPart;
                unsigned HighPart;
        } u;
        unsigned long long QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;


int main(int argc, char** argv){
        LARGE_INTEGER num1;
        num1.QuadPart = 0x1020304050607080;
        printf("Low: %x, high: %x, quad: %llx\n", num1.u.LowPart, num1.u.HighPart, num1.QuadPart);


        return 0;
}
```